# Gradle testCompile with mockito doesn't find the package

Tags: java, gradle, mockito

When I add

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}
```

to my `build.gradle`, the JAR file gets downloaded, but the compilation fails with

```
error: package org.mockito does not exist
```

and a bunch of follow-up errors. When I replace `testCompile` by `compile`, it works. I'm still rather beginner concerning Gradle, but `testCompile` sound just right to me. Moreover,

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
testCompile 'com.google.guava:guava-testlib:18.+'
```

work just fine. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With that configuration (and it's correct), the code that uses Mockito needs to be in `src/test/java` rather than `src/main/java`. `testCompile` defines compile dependencies for `src/test/java`.

Comment: Me stupid! All my tests are there, except for this one (which I forgot to move).

Comment: Omg. I've been struggling with that issue for a while. Made my day. Thanks